# Loop without a do

Tags: excel, vba

I don't know why VBA keeps returning me the message "loop without a do" for the following structure.

The error is related with the last "loop", that should be related with the first
Do Until(Do Until Cells(j, 9) <> "")

Ps: the idea is to have a form that will feed the sheet costs, where we can find start date, end date, course type and team members name.
Then, depending on course type, it should go to the other sheet (days), where you will find a calendar divided by months. Excel should find the right start and end date, then the right team member name and then, depending on course type, it should paint the cells between start and end date of different colours.

Can someone help me?

```
Sub days()

  Sheets("Costs").Activate

    j = 2
  Do Until Cells(j, 9) = ""
    Dim mes_startdate As Integer
    mes_startdate = Mid(Cells(j, 9), 4, 2)
    Dim mes_enddate As Integer
    mes_enddate = Mid(Cells(j, 10), 4, 2)
    Dim startdate As Date
    startdate = Cells(j, 9).Value
    Dim enddate As Date
    enddate = Cells(j, 10).Value
    Dim teammember As String
    teammember = Cells(j, 2).Value
    Dim coursetype As String
    coursetype = Cells(j, 4).Value

        Sheets("Days").Activate

        Dim celula1_linha_startdate As Integer

        If mes_startdate = "01" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B10").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "02" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B31").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "03" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B52").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "04" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B73").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "05" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B93").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "06" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B113").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "07" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B133").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "08" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B153").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "09" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B173").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "10" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B173").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "11" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B193").Row
        Else
        If mes_startdate = "12" Then
            celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B213").Row
        Else
        End If

        If mes_enddate = "01" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B10").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "02" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B31").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "03" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B52").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "04" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B73").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "05" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B93").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "06" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B113").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "07" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B133").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "08" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B153").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "09" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B173").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "10" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B173").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "11" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B193").Row
        Else
        If mes_enddate = "12" Then
            celula1_linha_enddate = Range("B213").Row
        Else
        End If

        nome_linha = celula1_linha_startdate + 2

        Do Until Cells(nome_linha, 1).Value = teammember

            nome_linha = celula1_linha_startdate + 1

        Loop

        startdate_coluna = 2

        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = startdate

            startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1

        Loop

        enddate_coluna = 2

        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value = enddate

            enddate_coluna = enddate_coluna + 1

        Loop

    If mes_startdate = mes_enddate Then

        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value

        If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "International Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 10498160
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12611584
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 192
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        'Nothing should happen
        End If

        startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1

        Loop
    Else
        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, 32).Value

        If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "International Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 10498160
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12611584
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 192
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        'Nothing should happen
        End If

        startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1
        Loop


        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, 1).Value

        If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "International Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 10498160
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 49407
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If
        If coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 12611584
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        End If

        If coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
            Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Select
            With Selection.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 192
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        Else
        'Nothing should happen
        End If

        enddate_coluna = enddate_coluna - 1
        Loop
    End If


    j = j + 1
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: It's because you have "endless" `If`s and `Else` with enough `End If` to close all your `If`s. change to `Select Case mes` , and then nested below `Case "01"` etc...

Comment: You have 7 Do's and 7 Loop(s), but your termination of IF and use of ELSE certainly won't compile.  Every IF block needs an END IF, count your IFs and your END IFs and place appropriately to close the logic or use Case Select structure for readability.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon what happened to the famous "Mat's Mug" ?

Comment: Hint: Any time you see repeating code (like copy and pasted with small changes) it is time to move the code in a subroutine.Then the structure of the program becomes more apparent and you will notice where you are missing an `End If` or `Loop` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Holyyy wow you've got a lot here - so I took a *shot* at cleaning this up for you because I've been there before, so I know your pain. A couple notes...

1. Put `Option Explicit` at the start of your modules and move all your declarations (`Dim`) to the top of the subroutine (outside of your loops). You can save some space by putting similar declarations on the same line, as I have here.
2. You need to utilize `Select Case`, `ElseIf` and arrays. I just go through 1 `Select Case` twice to get your values that you need for `mes_startdate` and `mes_enddate`. Another thing to note - not all `If` statements need an `Else` with them. If there's no case for `Else`, just exclude it altogether!
3. When changing the `Interior.Color` of a cell, you can kind of cheat by *only* changing the color, and leaving out the other details (if they're not changing).  That was able to cut out a lot of clutter. **Note how I also got rid of `Select` by just explicitly referring to the cells!**

There are others things in here that I cleaned up, but I'd just say you should compare and look for those changes yourself. I actually have no clue what you're trying to accomplish here, so this might not *work* but it's in the right format to move forward from here.

```
Option Explicit
Sub days()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim mes_startdate As Integer, mes_enddate As Integer
    Dim startdate As Date, enddate As Date
    Dim teammember As String, coursetype As String
    Dim celula1_linha_startdate As Integer, celula1_linha_enddate As Integer
    Dim nome_linha As Integer
    Dim startdate_coluna As Integer, enddate_coluna As Integer
    Dim myarray As Variant

    myarray = Array(mes_startdate, mes_enddate)
    Sheets("Costs").Activate

    j = 2

    Do Until Cells(j, 9) = ""

        mes_startdate = Mid(Cells(j, 9), 4, 2)
        mes_enddate = Mid(Cells(j, 10), 4, 2)
        startdate = Cells(j, 9).Value
        enddate = Cells(j, 10).Value
        teammember = Cells(j, 2).Value
        coursetype = Cells(j, 4).Value

        Sheets("Days").Activate

        For i = 0 To UBound(myarray)
            Select Case myarray(i)
            Case "01"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B10").Row
            Case "02"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B31").Row
            Case "03"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B52").Row
            Case "04"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B73").Row
            Case "05"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B93").Row
            Case "06"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B113").Row
            Case "07"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B133").Row
            Case "08"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B153").Row
            Case "09"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B173").Row
            Case "10"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B173").Row
            Case "11"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B193").Row
            Case "12"
                celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B213").Row
            End Select
        Next i

        nome_linha = celula1_linha_startdate + 2

        Do Until Cells(nome_linha, 1).Value = teammember
            nome_linha = celula1_linha_startdate + 1
        Loop

        startdate_coluna = 2

        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = startdate
            startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1
        Loop

        enddate_coluna = 2

        Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value = enddate
            enddate_coluna = enddate_coluna + 1
        Loop

        If mes_startdate = mes_enddate Then

            Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value

                If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                ElseIf coursetype = "International Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Interior.Color = 10498160
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Interior.Color = 49407
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Interior.Color = 12611584
                ElseIf coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, startdate_coluna).Interior.Color = 192
                End If

                startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1

            Loop

        Else

            Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, startdate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_startdate, 32).Value

                If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                ElseIf coursetype = "International Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 10498160
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 49407
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 12611584
                ElseIf coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 192
                End If

                startdate_coluna = startdate_coluna + 1
            Loop

            Do Until Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, enddate_coluna).Value = Cells(celula1_linha_enddate, 1).Value

                If coursetype = "E-learning" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent6
                ElseIf coursetype = "International Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 10498160
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Inside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 49407
                ElseIf coursetype = "National Courses Outside Rio de Janeiro" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 12611584
                ElseIf coursetype = "Other Courses" Then
                    Cells(nome_linha, enddate_coluna).Interior.Color = 192
                End If

                enddate_coluna = enddate_coluna - 1
            Loop

        End If

        j = j + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

**EDIT** I put this in Mat's [Rubberduck Indenter](http://rubberduckvba.com/Indentation) because I could see it was a bit all over the place, and I didn't feel like fixing that myself so I used this great tool! :)

Comment: There is still a lot of repeating code. I would recommend getting rid `celula1_linha_startdate = Range("B10").Row` type statements since it will always evaluate to 10. The rows can be hardcoded in an array, or better yet stored in a separate sheet for more flexibility.

Comment: @ja I did think about doing clever matching the array positions to the result of the `Select Case` (like if it's 1, 5, etc.), but I didn't want to over-complicate things for the poster. I might come back tomorrow and write a whole new solution from scratch :).

Comment: thank you very much for the help!! it helped A LOT! really! I am still having problems with these 2 lines here:mes_startdate = Mid(Cells(j, 9), 4, 2);  mes_enddate = Mid(Cells(j, 10), 4, 2). It says that it  says "type mismatch". Do you have any idea of whats going on?

Comment: I have another question: when you use my array it means both "components" of the needs to be equal at the same time to 01 or 02 or 03 etc.?

Comment: @PaulaEspinosaSantos You're getting a `Type Mismatch` there because you're trying to get an integer from that, but somehow you're getting something that isn't numeric with your `Mid` formula. You could try changing their types to `Variant` and see what your `Mid` formula is actually pulling.

Comment: And to your second point, no, that array is just testing the first one (separately), then testing the second one. It just substitutes the second one in after testing for the first one - they can still have different values.